# UI not updating until manually refreshed in Riverpodstate management

Tags: state-management, riverpod

I have read the only issue similar to my question but not quite the same issue. I have used Riverpod StateNotifier extensively in my dev but just this one screen where I am updating cart quantity that I am not getting desired performance. When I click the + sign to increase the quantity, nothing happens and for a long time I tweaked my code thinking it is the cause. But when I refreshed (via hot reload) the UI updated correctly. I am not sure why the UI doesn't immediately update on clicking the icon for changing quantity until UI is refreshed. Here are snippets of relevant codes and thanks for your insights as you help me. I am kind of foggy now.

FullCart Screen:

```
 const FilledCart({
    Key? key,
    required this.pId,
    required this.id,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.title,
    required this.price,
    required this.quantity,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    double subTotal = quantity * price;
    final cartDataState = ref.watch(cartControllerProvider);
    final cartData = cartDataState;
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .pushNamed(ProductDetailsScreen.routeName, arguments: pId);
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 150,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                width: 2,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
              )),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 130,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    image: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 10),
              Flexible(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Flexible(
                          child: Text(
                            title,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {},
                            child: const Icon(
                              Icons.close,
                              size: 20,
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 7,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        const Text(
                          'Price: ',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                        Flexible(
                          child: Text(
                            '\$ $price',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: const [
                        Text(
                          'Shipping: ',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                        Flexible(
                          child: Text(
                            '\$ 20.00',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        const Text(
                          'SubTotal: ',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                        Flexible(
                          child: Text(
                            '\$ $subTotal',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: const Text(
                            '-',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          quantity.toString(),
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            ref
                                .read(cartControllerProvider.notifier)
                                .addToCart(pId, imageUrl, price, title);
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            '+',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

cartControllerProvider:

```
final cartControllerProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<CartListController, List<Cart>>(
  (ref) => CartListController(),
);

class CartListController extends StateNotifier<List<Cart>> {
  final Map<String, Cart> _cartList = {};

  Map<String, Cart> get cartList => _cartList;

  CartListController([List<Cart>? state]) : super(state ?? <Cart>[]);

  double get totalAmount {
    double total = 0.0;
    _cartList.forEach((key, value) {
      total += value.quantity * value.price;
    });
    return total;
  }

  void addToCart(
    String pId,
    String imageUrl,
    double price,
    String title,
  ) {
    if (_cartList.containsKey(pId)) {
      _cartList.update(
        pId,
        (value) => Cart(
          cartId: value.cartId,
          imageUrl: value.imageUrl,
          title: value.title,
          price: value.price,
          quantity: value.quantity + 1,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      _cartList.putIfAbsent(
        pId,
        () => Cart(
          cartId: DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
          imageUrl: imageUrl,
          title: title,
          price: price,
          quantity: 1,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot showing current quantity only after reload of UI]

Comment: I see the problem but my solucion will depend on how you are using: `final cartDataState = ref.watch(cartControllerProvider);`. Can you show that please?

Comment: I am not using cartDataState at all. It was initially defined for use until I saw that I could read the provider directly to access the addToCart() function. Not sure how I could use the cartDataState if that solves the problem. I have posted the full code where that is defined. Thanks for wanting to help.

Comment: Juan Carlos, I hope I answered your question to enable you point out the problem as you see it? I will appreciate your insight to solving this issue soon. Thanks partner.

Comment: Have you tried: state = _cartList after you udpate your cart in your addToCart method ? I think the StateNotifier is not detecting the change because you don't change the state property.

Comment: I did as follows and still no cigar. I also tried a variety without the spread operator and same result. Thanks for trying to assist me though.

Comment: Sorry this is my code snippet: `state = [
        ...state,
        _cartList.update(
          pId,
          (value) => Cart(
            cartId: value.cartId,
            imageUrl: value.imageUrl,
            title: value.title,
            price: value.price,
            quantity: value.quantity + 1,
          ),
        )
      ];`

Comment: The way you're using StateNotifier is incorrect. You should not have any state outside of the "state" variable, and your state should be immutable. See the example in the docs https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/state_notifier_provider

Comment: Remi, I am honored that you took the time out to chime in on this issue. As a new ambassador for RIverpod, I admit I am just a beginner. Could you help me learn faster by pointing out my error and probably the fix as well? I promise to read the documentation again and again as I have done but still making errors. That one pointer can make all the difference in the world. Where I am today is because of effort to learn but there's still some shortcomings on my part. Thanks for your help as I am looking and not knowing what I have done wrong. Thanks

Comment: revised code as follows and still no luck. Only issue is with UI not updating. Please help with at least a pointer on where to look in my code if no suggested ans.  I assigned _catList to my state: state = _catList;  after the update called with _catList.update()